# Android : How to add QA build variant into the internal testing track to test the Android's in-app update API?

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

I have implemented the Android's in-app update API into my android application by following the steps given by Official documentation: [Google Official Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) and [Google Official Document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479) and now I want to test the in-app update flow with my QA build variant.

I am getting an error while trying to upload the android QA build variant into the internal app sharing upload page  ([internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing)) i.e. internal testing track of Google play console.

I am not sure but I think this happens because of different application id (i.e. package name) as I append .qa suffix to original application id. (applicationIdSuffix '.qa')

Is there any way to upload the QA build into the testing track of Google play console by keeping suffix to application id.

Also, the official document says that "To set the priority for an update, use inAppUpdatePriority field under Edits.tracks.releases in the Google Play Developer API. Priority can only be set when rolling out a new release, and cannot be changed later." Does that mean I won't be able to test the update priority with QA build environment and thus the immediate update?

Is there any way where I can test all the above things? Please help...!